# Why reversing the arraylist is not showing any result?

Tags: powershell, arraylist

I am trying to reverse the queue and make it as stack. But it is not showing any output.

```
$queue = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$queue.Add("Object1") | Out-Null
$queue.Add("Object2") | Out-Null
"=========== Queue ================"
foreach ($i in $queue) {
    $i
}

$stack = $queue.Reverse()
"=========== stack ================"
foreach ($i in $stack) {
    $i
}
```

I expected the result like below

```
=========== Queue ================
Object1
Object2
=========== stack ================
Object2
Object1
```

But the stack result is not giving any value as below

```
=========== Queue ================
Object1
Object2
=========== stack ================
```

What is wrong here? How to correct it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.Reverse()` does not return an object, it reverses the elements of the object that it is called on:

```
$queue = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$queue.Add("Object1") | Out-null
$queue.Add("Object2") | Out-null
"=========== Queue ================"
foreach ($i in $queue){
    $i
}

$queue.Reverse()  # <<<<<<<<<< Reverse $queue *in place*.
"=========== stack ================"
foreach($i in $queue)
{
    $i
}
```

Comment: For future reference, `$queue.Reverse` would have shown the overload signature for `Reverse()`, including the fact that it always returns `void`

Comment: Or Get-Member -InputObject $queue would show it as well.

Comment: @EBGreen: Indeed, `Get-Member -InputObject $queue Reverse` works too, but the advantage of `$queue.Reverse` (aside from being shorter) is that you get each overload on its own line, which is easier to read, especially with many overloads.

Comment: @EBGreen But after reversing queue still giving the name as queue doesn't make sense. Is it not possible to assign to another collection named 'stack' from this collection 'queue'?

Comment: Sure if you want to. Just reverse it then assign it to another variable. Or assign it then reverse the other one.

Comment: As foir the name being the same, it makes sense to me. You have a list. You told the list to reverse itself and it did.